# DB2 giving nio.unsupportedcharsetexception CP836 while trying to access date fields

Tags: date, timestamp, db2, driver, dbeaver

DB2 giving nio.unsupportedcharsetexception CP836 while trying to access date/timestamp fields. I am using db2jcc4.jar as driver for DB2.
Am getting the below exception
**java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: Cp836**

I am trying with both  DBeaver and Squirrel both are giving only this much stacktrace.

and am using z/os platform
java version: 1.8
able to select column value, if that column is not of date/timestamp type
connection string : jdbc:db2://********:451/***B

Comment: Also, check the JRE/jvm/jdk that  you are using with DBeaver.   See https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/errorcode-4220-received-when-using-ccsid-13124cp836-connect-as400-db-using-db2-jcc-type-4-driver

Comment: updated the question and please let me know any further information required

Comment: Please edit the question to show the __full__ exception text in plain text, and the connection-string (with masked private information).

Comment: If the following command been run from the `lib` directory doesn't return any rows, then you should try another jvm. `jar -tvf charsets.jar | grep IBM836`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a configuration matter.

Check whose jre you are using with DBeaver (Oracle/Sun, IBM, or other).

See https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/errorcode-4220-received-when-using-ccsid-13124cp836-connect-as400-db-using-db2-jcc-type-4-driver

Specifically this advice:

> IBM has a charset support for every CCSID IBM machines deal with.

> Oracle/Sun JDK/JRE uses charsets.jar to provide character mapping
> between UTF-8 and various code pages.
>
> Oracle/Sun jre has separate international installations and that
> localized install would not have all conversion classes.  So you will
> need to obtain a full JDK installation.
>
> It is best to use latest IBM JDK. It contains both rt.jar and
> charsets.jar containing the class file ByteToCharCp836.class.
>
> Download here:
>
> > https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/index.html

Comment: i am using oracle jre.. i will try with ibm